# chromedriver.exe not working in Windows Server 2012

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium and `chromedriver` for testing. While running my code on window server 2012, the task manager is showing the `chromedriver.exe` process is running but after 60 second.

I am getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome
>   binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325
>   (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.2
>   x86_64) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
>   desiredCapabilities) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor
>   commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()

Following is the my code segment where the exception is thrown:

The `chromedriver.exe` is inside `C:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsitename.com\httpdocs\bin`

Code:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsitename.com\httpdocs");
driver.Url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
```

Can anyone suggest me , where is the problem, B'coz `chromedriver.exe` running process is their in task bar when the program execution starts.

Comment: Have you tried this`driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsitename.com\httpdocs\bin");` 
   `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl( ("https://www.google.co.in/");`

Comment: i have tried the above path but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working java code to launch chrome and open the url entered :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         WebDriver driver;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path_to_Chrome.exe\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");
         driver.close();
}
```

I hope this will work

Comment: u can take reference from it

Comment: getting exception - chrome failed to start (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a4 21281abb7)  ,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)

Comment: my c# code :  ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
                co.BinaryLocation = @"C:\inetpub\vhosts\myweb\httpdocs\bin";        driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
               driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("website name");